# Мультиязычный сайт на Laravel 7, как реализовать?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

Саму смену языка реализовал.

В Middleware идёт проверка, есть ли в URL директория языка. Если есть, то выставляется App::setLocale($locale) и загружается страница.

При смене языка редактирую URL, в начало ссылки подставляю директорию, соответствующую выбранному языку.
При смене языка записывается кука с значением языка.

Все Route объединил в группу.

Остановился на моменте, когда значение языка в куках не равно значению языка директории (такое может быть, когда пользователь сменил язык, но в последствии вернулся на сайт по старой ссылке, соответствующей другому языку).

Хотел при отличии куки и языка в урл делать редирект. Но редирект не будет сохранять setLocale и получается бесконечный цикл. Может в $next($request) как то можно передать другие значения URL? Но скорее всего это моя больная фантазия)

Как реализовать смену языка при несоотвествии языка в куках и языка в урл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте или куки или урлы, иначе у вас всегда будут конфликты. Те:

1. Middleware проверяет урлы и отдает страницы согласно установленной Locale
2. Middleware проверяет куки и отдает страницы согласно установленной Locale
   Добавлю, что использование первой логики лучше для SEO оптимизации сайта: вы не будете многоязычием вводить в заблуждение краулеры поисковых систем